# Foreach command ,initiation error

Tags: foreach, tcl

This is the list i have

```
  set session_list [list ../../TIMING_ANALYSIS_CRPR/FUNC_ss28_0.85V_0.95V_0.85V_125C_RCmax/reports.15_03_10-22/SAVED_SESSION 
../../TIMING_ANALYSIS_CRPR/FUNC_ff28_0.85V_0.95V_0.85V_m40C_Cmin/reports.15_03_10-22/SAVED_SESSION]


 foreach j $session_list {
 set x  [string trimleft  $j  "../../TIMING_ANALYSIS_CRPR/ "]

}

foreach item $x {
puts "create_scenario -name $item "
}
```

so what i want is my output to the list be given out as :

```
create_scenario -name FUNC_ss28_0.85V_0.95V_0.85V_125C_RCmax/reports.15_03_10-22/SAVED_SESSION 
create_scenario -name FUNC_ff28_0.85V_0.95V_0.85V_m40C_Cmin/reports.15_03_10-22/SAVED_SESSION
```

IN the top stated code ,it does not read the first foreach command and does not display the whole list

Comment: `create_scenario -name  FUNC_ss28_0.85V_0.95V_0.85V_125C_RCmax -image ./../FUNC_ss28_0.85V_0.95V_0.85V_125C_RCmax/reports.15_03_10-22/SAVED_SESSION`
`create_scenario -name  FUNC_ff28_0.85V_0.95V_0.85V_m40C_Cmin -image ./../UNC_ff28_0.85V_0.95V_0.85V_m40C_Cmin/reports.15_03_10-22/SAVED_SESSION`
How do i get this as my output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the value of `x` in each loop which will cause the `x` value to get overwritten.

You have to use `lappend` command

```
 foreach j $session_list {
      lappend x  [string trimleft  $j  "../../TIMING_ANALYSIS_CRPR/ "]
 }

 foreach item $x {
     puts "create_scenario -name $item "
 }
```

**Output :**

```
create_scenario -name FUNC_ss28_0.85V_0.95V_0.85V_125C_RCmax/reports.15_03_10-22/SAVED_SESSION 
create_scenario -name FUNC_ff28_0.85V_0.95V_0.85V_m40C_Cmin/reports.15_03_10-22/SAVED_SESSION
```

Reference : [lappend](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lappend.htm)

Comment: Thanks @Dinesh , yes now i get it ..the files were getting overwritten !! thanx btw !!

Answer (score 0):

`[string trimleft]` doesn't do what you think it does. The line:

```
string trimleft  $j  "../../TIMING_ANALYSIS_CRPR/ "
```

basically means: remove the characters `.` and `/` and `T` and `I` and `M` and `N` and `G` and `_` and `A` and `N` and `L` and `Y` and `S` and `C` and `R` and `P` and (single space) form the left of the string.

What you want instead is regsub:

```
regsub {^../../TIMING_ANALYSIS_CRPR/} $j ""
```

Comment: Well Trim left i think removes the characters you specify from the left hand side .and while using regsub command ,it yields the same result as before !!

Comment: Yes but the "characters" don't mean what you think it means. It doesn't mean trim the "string" from the left but any of the specified "characters". For example, `trim left $x abc` and `trim left $x cab` and `trim left $x bca` all do exactly the same thing because all 3 commands trims any characters `a` or `b` or `c` from the left.

Comment: Also, I've tested that regsub so I'm quite sure it works. Are you sure you're assigning its result back to `$j`? Like this: `set j [regsub ......]`